# Conection refused error for telnet and ssh

Tags: ssh, telnet

I try to telnet to one of my systems 172.16.xx.z from 172.16.xx.y, but the response i get is-

> sudo telnet 172.16.xx.z
>
> Trying 172.16.xx.z...
>
> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Same for localhost-

> sudo telnet localhost
>
> Trying ::1...
>
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
>
> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

And the same experience with ssh:

> sudo ssh 172.16.xx.z
>
> ssh: connect to host 172.16.xx.z port 22: Connection refused

Any guesses what could be wrong here?
Both my systems run on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you `sudo ssh` to connect? You can use ssh client in user mode!

To install ssh server on an Ubuntu box, run

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then ssh to that box should work. Telnet is not to be used over the internet due to lack of encryption.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with telnet is that no one runs the telnet daemon on a modern Linux. As for ssh, make sure that sshd is installed and running, and that port 22 is appropriately open on the firewall.